# How can I stream music I have in my Ubuntu One account to Subsonic in my Android smartphone?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

How can I stream music I have in my Ubuntu One account to Subsonic in my Android smartphone?

The Android Subsonic app asks me for:

- Server address
- Username
- Password

I want to use my Ubuntu One subscription to stream my music. What information do I have to enter in that fields?

Subsonic have an option to Test connection but it isn't working with the data I populate that fields.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [Ubuntu One Music](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.sourceforge.subsonic.u1m) app almost certainly rather than the full Subsonic client (for several reasons).

In any case, you can get your [mobile credentials](https://one.ubuntu.com/phones/) and then use `https://streaming.one.ubuntu.com/` as the endpoint. You can read more on [the developer documentation site](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/music/stream_music/cloud/).